# Error: Redefinition of Class (C++)

Tags: c++, class, redefinition

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting the following error:

**error: redefinition of 'TimeDuration'**

```
// TimeDuration.cpp

#define HOUR 3600
#define MIN 60

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "TimeDuration.h"

using namespace std;

TimeDuration::TimeDuration() {
    seconds = 0;
}

void TimeDuration::setDuration(const int sec) {
    seconds = sec;
}

void TimeDuration::display() {
    // Some code to display the time
}
```

The error is showing in my header file.

```
// TimeDuration.h

class TimeDuration {
    private:
        int seconds;
    public:
        TimeDuration();                     
        void setDuration(const int sec);    
        void display();                     
};
```

Comment: Have you got header guards in place? Post the exact compiler error output if you can

Comment: ./TimeDuration.h:5:7: error: redefinition of 'TimeDuration'
class TimeDuration {

Comment: ./TimeDuration.h:5:7: note: previous definition is here
class TimeDuration {

Comment: @raychul, clarify, is that your complete TimeDuration.h file? If so you need to add header gaurds.

Comment: Alright, I'm not really familiar with headers guards, but I'll look it up. Thanks!

Comment: Probably you have not got header guards and have included that header in multiple files???? If so Google header guards and why you need them.

Comment: Thanks! I added header guards and everything works perfectly now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is probably because you don't have header guards in TimeDuration.h

A standard way to header guard is to at the beginning of the file write:

```
#ifndef TIME_DURATION_H
#define TIME_DURATION_H
```

and at the end of the file:

```
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
#pragma once
```

in your TimeDuration.h file , at the starting